# Not sure if I'm doing this substitution question right

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Go with

$$f(x) = \sin(2x).$$

Give a clean formula for the function h[x] defined by

$$h(x) = \int_0^x f(s) ds$$

How are $f(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}h(x)$ related?

Is the outcome an accident? Why or why not?​

My answer:

$$h(x) = (2\cos(2x)) - 1$$

$$h'(x) = -4\sin(2x)$$

When they say $f(s)$ do they mean to use integration by substitution? Are $h'(x)$ and $f(x)$ supposed to both equal $\sin(2x)$?

Comment: [mathjax references](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) to help you typset maths.

Comment: Is that $\int_0^xtf(s)\,ds$, or $\int_0^xtf(s)\,dt$, or something else?

Comment: Are you still here, vkygul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is

$$h(x)= \int_0^x f(s) \, ds= \int_0^x \sin(2s) \, ds$$

Hence $$h(x) = -\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\frac12$$